# How to encode a string in a QR code using zxing on Android?

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing

I am trying to generate a QR code using Zxing on Android. Since java.awt.image.BufferedImage is not included in Android, I am not sure how to create the QR code image on Android.

EDIT:
I don't want my application to require internet access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please look at the zxing source code under `android/`. In the `.encode` package you will see an example of exactly how to encode a QR code in Android. Yes, you can't use, and don't need to use `BufferedImage`.

Comment: Thanks now I have successfully encoded the QR code and have sent it over to the android application. Then it gets it as a BitMap object. Now how do I decode it?

Comment: Well you could look at the `.qrcode` package for the `Detector` and `Decoder`. But if you're encoding info just to send it to another activity and decode it... why not just send the original data?

Comment: @SeanOwen this is working for any text but if i want to encode url then may i need to use same intent.putExtra(Intents.Encode.TYPE, Contents.Type.TEXT);  because there is not Type for URL

Comment: A short example would be even more helpful, imho.

Answer (score 8):

I found this to be a helpful http://codeisland.org/2013/generating-qr-codes-with-zxing/

Using the above resource, I created a utility method as follows:

```
public static Bitmap encodeToQrCode(String text, int width, int height){
    QRCodeWriter writer = new QRCodeWriter();
    BitMatrix matrix = null;
    try {
        matrix = writer.encode(text, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 100, 100);
    } catch (WriterException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++){
            bmp.setPixel(x, y, matrix.get(x,y) ? Color.BLACK : Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
    return bmp;
}
```

Comment: @Steve Paul will it create bitmap of provided user string e/g (123+ghnn-ggg)

Comment: Hi Erum, yes I have used it in my application. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is the [google charts API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes.html). It is a simple rest API that will give you a png file. If you don't want your application to require the internet you have more work on your hands, but it can be done. [com.google.zxing.qrcode.encoder](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk/core/src/com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder) are the classes that will generate a QR for you. I never figured out exactly how to use them, but I think it returns a matrix that represents the QR, you'd have to work out how to draw it to a canvas or something.

Comment: Thanks Tim. But I don't want my application to require internet access. So could you please suggest me any useful URLs?